# Check if all values are unique in a div using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have select box which no select generates number of textboxes in a `div`.
Now there are three field

`display_name[], user_name[], and user_password[]`

The code for that is :

```
<select name="license" id="dropdown" class="form-control" required="required">                                                 
  <option  value="default" >Select</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
</select>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#dropdown").change(function() {
            var selVal = $(this).val();
            $("#pttuserdiv").html('');
            if(selVal > 0) {
                for(var i = 1; i<= selVal; i++) {
                    $("#pttuserdiv").append(`
                    <div class="col-sm-3 col-sm-offset-1">
                        <div class="form-group label-floating">
                            <label class="control-label">Display Name</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="display_name[]" required >
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-3 col-sm-offset-1">
                        <div class="form-group label-floating">
                            <label class="control-label">Username</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control validateLocation"  name="user_name[]" id="user_name" required >
                        </div>
                    </div> 
                    <div class="col-sm-3 col-sm-offset-1">
                        <div class="form-group label-floating">
                            <label class="control-label">Password</label>
                            <input type="password" class="form-control" name="user_password[]" required >
                        </div>
                    </div>`);
                }
            }
        });
    });
</script>

<div class="row">
<div id="pttuserdiv">

</div>
</div>
```

Now I want the user_name[] field to be unique.

How do I do that ?
I want to display error or alert if user input same username again in user_name[].

Comment: `id`s should be unique and your need to handle the change event for the input box.

Comment: If I understood, before you save newly created user, you want to compare its username against all existing usernames. But from your code is unclear, where you store all existing - previously created users.

Comment: @Waldermarlce I am not storing them or creating them that, it is to be done on server side (PHP)  but I want to check on client side if all values are unique for that id or name

Comment: @Rajan And this is the problem... If all users are stored on server, you can't validate new user on client. You must send the given new username to the server and validate it there.

Comment: @WaldemarIce that i have handled but i just want unique string of username on client side

Comment: @Rajan Then use AJAX. Catch onsubmit event, send username to the server with AJAX, validate it on the server, and in AJAX response, send info if user is, or is it not unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following approach

- **Bind** `keyup` event and check user's `input` for the current input box.
- **Check** if the *current input value* is same as other username values
- **If yes**, then *highlight the input box*.

**Demo**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#dropdown").change(function() {
    var selVal = $(this).val();
    $("#pttuserdiv").html('');
    if (selVal > 0) {
      for (var i = 1; i <= selVal; i++) {
        $("#pttuserdiv").append('<div class="col-sm-3 col-sm-offset-1"><div class="form-group label-floating"><label class="control-label">Display Name</label><input type="text" class="form-control" name="display_name[]" required ></div></div><div class="col-sm-3 col-sm-offset-1"><div class="form-group label-floating"><label class="control-label">Username</label><input type="text" class="form-control validateLocation"  name="user_name[]" id="user_name" required ></div></div> <div class="col-sm-3 col-sm-offset-1"><div class="form-group label-floating"><label class="control-label">Password</label><input type="password" class="form-control" name="user_password[]" required ></div></div>');
      }
      $( "[name='user_name[]']" ).off( "keyup" );
      $( "[name='user_name[]']" ).on( "keyup", function(){
          var isFound = false;
          var value = $(this).val();
          $( "[name='user_name[]']" ).not(this).each( function(){
               if ( this.value == value )
               {
                   isFound = true;
               }
          });
          $(this).toggleClass( "highlight", isFound );
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.highlight
{
   border-color : red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="license" id="dropdown" class="form-control" required="required">                                                 
  <option  value="default" >Select</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
</select>

<script type="text/javascript">
</script>

<div class="row">
  <div id="pttuserdiv">

  </div>
</div>
```

**Note** - **Id** doesn't play any role in my code, but as a good practice keep the ids of all elements unique.

Comment: How can I keep all IDs unique? Can I take id as array?? Like I took it for name ?

Comment: when you are iterating, you can append the counter value to the `username`.

Comment: if i loop though using PHP i need to refresh the page to get the number of textbox in post and then generate that number of text boxes

Comment: @Rajan I am not able to relate how PHP has anything to do with your original question.

Comment: actually i am confused how to iterate and add ids dynamically? PHP i use on server side, so i was thinking that i might have to use PHP for iteration